# Query Builder vs. ORM?

Tags: orm, backend, server-side, query-builder

What is the difference between a query builder and an ORM that developers use in their backend server-side code/logic for interacting with their database? It seems like the query builder can fulfill the goal of coding in the same language you are choosing to write the backend server-side code/logic to work with the database. However, I don't understand why an ORM comes in the picture then.

Answer (score 0):

SQL query returns records (scalars) that do not automatically load more data if needed.

ORM can return you a Java object (say Person) with actual working methods that can load more data from database (without writing more queries explicitly).

For example if you call person.getAddress() it can return Address object that's just loads from database on the fly. Without writing new "select address" query.

Whatever is returned form SQL query (builder) does not work like that.